# go-gin request cancellation

Tags: go, httprequest, go-gin, go-context

How do I cancel further processing if the connection is closed before 10 seconds?

There is `c.Request.Context().Done()` but coudn't find an example on how to use it.

```
func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.GET("/ping", func(c *gin.Context) {
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Second) // or some db operation
        log.Print("Processing")
        c.JSON(200, gin.H{
            "message": "pong",
        })
    })
    r.Run()
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can run the long-running operation asynchronously and have it send on a channel to signal completion.

Then you block on that completion channel and `c.Request.Context().Done()` with a `select` statement:

```
func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.GET("/ping", func(c *gin.Context) {
        signal := make(chan struct{}, 1)

        go longRunningOperation(signal)

        select {
            case <-signal:
                close(signal) // remember to clean up after yourself
                // move on, will print "Processing"
    
            case <-c.Request.Context().Done():
                // abort
                return
        }

        log.Print("Processing")
        c.JSON(200, gin.H{
            "message": "pong",
        })
    })
    r.Run()
}


func longRunningOperation(signal chan<- struct{}) {
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    signal <- struct{}{} // signal that this operation has finished
}
```

The disadvantage with this approach is that, *as-is*, the long-running operation itself would keep executing.

Goroutines exit when the `main` function of your program returns, which is not the case in an actual `gin` server. So this might not be what you want.

In the case of a database operation, most APIs require a `context.Context` parameter, which can be used to detect request cancellation. So you could pass the `c.Request.Context()` down the call chain to make sure the async long-running operation also terminates when the client disconnects.

```
func Handler(c *gin.Context) {
    signal := make(chan struct{}, 1)
    go longRunningOperation(c.Request.Context(), signal)
    ...
}

func longRunningOperation(ctx context.Context, signal chan<- struct{}) {
    if err := doSomethingContext(ctx); err != nil {
        return
    }
    signal <- struct{}{} // signal that this operation has finished (successfully)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this approach is that despite the request being cancelled, the doSomethingContext will still be executed.

If you place a print in that function, you will see it in the terminal, even after the context being cancelled.

This is even worse than not having the timeout at all, because when the request is cancelled, the app answers back to the user saying it did nothing, but in fact it kept executing

But I also don't know the solution for this either...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).